# How to remove only one of a duplicate value in c++

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates, max, average

I am writing code that removes the minimum and maximum values from a vector, and then averages the remaining values.

I have this code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

double averageWithoutOutliers(vector<int> values) {
    double max = *max_element(values.begin(),values.end());
    values.erase(std::remove(values.begin(), values.end(), max), values.end());

    double min = *min_element(values.begin(),values.end());
    values.erase(std::remove(values.begin(), values.end(), min), values.end());
    auto n = values.size(); 
    double average = 0.0;
    if ( n != 0) {
        average = accumulate( values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0) / n; 
        return average;
    }
    else 
        return min;
}
```

This code works, except for when there are multiple maximum values. How would one go about either checking for duplicate maximum values, or only removing one of a duplicate value?

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove()` removes ALL elements that match the specified value.  If you only want to remove 1 element, then use `vector::erase()` instead:

```cpp
double averageWithoutOutliers(vector<int> values) {
    if (values.size() < 2)
        return ...; // or throw...

    auto iter = max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
    values.erase(iter);

    iter = min_element(values.begin(), values.end());
    double min = *iter;
    values.erase(iter);

    if (!values.empty())
        return accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0) / values.size();

    return min;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
double averageWithoutOutliers(vector<int> values) {
    if (values.size() < 2)
        return ...; // or throw...

    auto iters = minmax_element(values.begin(), values.end());

    auto min_iter = iters.first;
    double min = *min_iter;

    auto max_iter = iters.second;

    if (max_iter < min_iter)
        std::swap(min_iter, max_iter);
    values.erase(max_iter);
    values.erase(min_iter);

    if (!values.empty())
        return accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0) / values.size();

    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d approach it a little differently:

```
double average(const std::vector<double>& values) {
    if (values.size() < 2)
        return 0.0;
    auto ends = std::minmax_element(values.begin(), values.end());
    double sum = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(),
        -(*ends.first + *ends.second));
    return sum / (values.size() - 2);
}
```